# Capacity of a capacitor with multiple dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

The question that I have is how should I calculate the total capacity of the capacitor described in the picture below:
[image: Capacitor Diagram]

I tried taking Air, $C_1$,$C_2$ as parallel capacitors (They should have the same potential difference) with their effective being $C_{eq1}$ and taking $C_4$ and $C_5$ in series and adding up their effective in parallel with $C_3$ as $C_{eq3}$ and then taking $C_{eq1}$ and $C_{eq3}$ in series to get $C_{eqT}$.

[image]

But I checked my answer with a $TA$ and they said that I should take $C_2$ and Air as parallel and $C_1$ and $C_3$ in series. I can't understand which one is the right answer.

Comment: Does the final answer given differ from your answer?

Comment: yes. It says you should take air and C2 separately. but I don't know if that is true or not.

Comment: No I didn't mean the procedure, I meant do the ANSWERS match? Because sometimes you can proceed in different ways but the final result matters.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Interesting. Even I await an answer